# How do I reset the icons in the notification area back to their default locations?

Tags: 10.10, gnome-panel

I restarted my computer and now they are all out of order, how do I put them back in the proper order?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "out of order"?

Comment: @DoR, refer to the new screenshot.

Comment: I have been having this same issue since Ubuntu 10.04.  Haven't seen it on 10.10 yet.  Have you done the upgrade?

Comment: Yes I am using 10.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your current panel configuration so it is no longer used:

`mv ~/.gconf/apps/panel ~/panel_backup`

Log out and then log back in, you will now have the default panel setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can move any panel applet by right clicking on it (right click just between the items in the notification area), unticking 'Lock to Panel' and clicking 'move'. You can then drag it along the panel with your mouse and drop it with a left click. Aftwerwards, right click again and tick 'Lock to Panel'.

[image: right click move]

You can refresh the panel by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and entering `killall gnome-panel` or you can enter `xkill` and then click on the panel.

[image: killall gnome-panel]

Comment: This did not arrange the icons in their proper order.

Comment: Try right click > move, making sure 'Lock to Panel' is unticked.

Comment: You also want to make sure to Lock them back in place when you're done moving them, or they'll just jump around again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever plugged in an extrnal monitor or moved the icons around?  I noticed this seemed to start for me after plugging in an external monitor and enabling it in the Nvidia settings for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Another trick is to killall gnome-panel. This works mainly for visual glitches, but may also work for arrangement.